# Apache service is not getting started , 80 port blocked or used

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Suddenly i faced the above issued mentioned in the title , I clicked on the start service in xamp software for starting of with Apache sever but i couldnt , Below is what the error was throw up with

```
    Problem detected!
    5:55:26 PM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
    5:55:26 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
    5:55:26 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
    5:55:26 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

And Yes i have tried methods ,Event i can't find web development agent in services msc

I don't know what to do , A help will be great .

Comment: Have you got Skype running?, skype and xampp both try to bind to port 80, if so, go to skype settings and change the port number there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a program running on port 80 already, so apache cant bind to that port, 
Skype is one of those programs, tell Skype to use a different port in it's settings, or simply close it.

If its not skype try running: `netstat -a -b` in console (cmd) to see what program is using port 80, then close it.

You could also run `resmon.exe` as this has an easier interface.

Answer (score 0):

In same cases, the software like Skype will automatically take Port 80. try to change port or uninstall it.

if it is port issue, go to ms dos and follow this

NETSTAT [-a] [-e] [-n] [-s] [-p proto] [-r] [interval]

-a Displays all connections and listening ports.

-e Displays Ethernet statistics. This may be combined with the -s option.

-n Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.

-p proto Shows connections for the protocol specified by proto; proto may be TCP or UDP. If used with the -s option to display per-protocol statistics, proto may be TCP, UDP, or IP.

-r Displays the routing table.

-s Displays per-protocol statistics. By default, statistics are shown for TCP, UDP and IP; the -p option may be used to specify a subset of the default.

interval Redisplays selected statistics, pausing interval seconds between each display. Press CTRL+C to stop redisplaying statistics. If omitted, netstat will print the current configuration information once.